# MVC 4 - Ajax - Replace one partial one view with another

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-ajax

I'm trying to replace the contents of a div in a Main view with partial views depending on which @Ajax.ActionLink is clicked.

Initally I load the _CaseLoad partial view then I would like to be able to switch between the two partial views _CaseLoad and _Vacancies when I click on the relevant ActionLink. I have bothe partial views and the Index view in the 'Main' folder.

When I click on the 'Vacancies' link it briefly shows the LoadingElementID but it does not replace the _CaseLoad partial view with _Vacancies partial view?

Controller Action (MainController):

```
    public ActionResult Index(int page = 1, string searchTerm = null)
    {
        MainIndexViewModel model = new MainIndexViewModel()
        // Populate Model

        return View(model);

    }
```

Main Index View:

```
@model Project.WebUI.Models.MainIndexViewModel

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Index";
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div id="MainIndex">
        <div id="Menu">

            @Ajax.ActionLink("CaseLoad", "_CaseLoad", "Main", null, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "Main", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "GET",
                LoadingElementId = "busycycle" }) |

            @Ajax.ActionLink("Vacancies", "_Vacancies", "Main", null, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "Main", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "GET",
                LoadingElementId = "busycycle" })

        </div><hr/>


        <div id="busycycle" style="display:none;"><img src="~/Content/images/preloader-w8-cycle-black.gif" /></div>
        <div id="Main">
            @Html.Partial("_CaseLoad")
        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your call to @Ajax.ActionLink is wrong, you are doing this:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("CaseLoad", "_CaseLoad", "Main", null, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "Main", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "GET",
            LoadingElementId = "busycycle" })
```

Which means your link text is "CaseLoad", and the action to be called in "MainController" is "_CaseLoad"? Isn't "_CaseLoad" the name of your partial view?

To fix this, you must create CaseLoad and a Vacancies actions in your MainController, make both methods return PartialView("_CaseLoad.cshtml", model); or PartialView("_Vacancies.cshtml, model) like below:

```
public ActionResult CaseLoad(int page = 1, string searchTerm = null)
{
    MainIndexViewModel model = new MainIndexViewModel()
    // Poopulate Model

    return PartialView("_CaseLoad.cshtml", model);
}
```

I just cut off all implementation details just to get you an idea about how to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say try using a browser that has a good set of developer tools (I'd recommend Chrome) and hit <kbd>F12</kbd>. With the dev tools open, switch to the Network Tab, and then click on your ajax link. The Loading element only shows while the request is in progress, it doesn't necessarily mean it succeeded. By using the Network tab, you should be able to see what the response from the Ajax request was and determine if it was an error, and what the resulting partial view actually was.